# How to use OAuth2 Browser based authentication, and then verify the record on the server

Tags: php, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I have a browser-based app (single page, AngularJS) and am using hello to use third party signin such as Google, FB, Soundcloud, etc.

My app uses a PHP API server.

What's a good way to have the user able to login using Google, but also verify the user on the server side?

I was considering:

- The browser app performs an implicit grant with google/fb/etc
- I then transfer the access_token from the client to the server, then use, for example, a google-api-php-client with my `app id`, secret and the user `access_token`?  Using their API such as `/me`? (which grant type would this be?)
- Retrieve some key from the third-party (facebook_id, email, etc), match it against a user in my database, and then consider the user authenticated?

Also, should I perform this on each API request?  Or should I just stash the `access_token` for a bit and assume that the user is still valid until the key expires?

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that not all of those providers support the implicit flow. But assuming they do, the `access_token` you get for each will be proof that the user authenticated with that system, not necessarily that they have access to call *your* API. You still need something that asserts that "someone@gmail.com can 'read' resource X in your system"

You probably need something that translates whatever you get from Google, Soundcloud, etc. into a token your app understands. A simple(r) format is to use JWT. (Json Web Tokens).

`App -> Intermmediary -> Soundcloud/Google
   <-JWT--+        <---whavetever-+`

and then:

`App - (JWT) -> API`

JWT are easy to manipulate, validate and verify. See [jwt.io](http://jwt.io)

You might want to look at [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) also for some additional information (specifically on AngularJS front-ends)

Comment: So if I understand, I could pack enough into the JWT that would prove the user is authenticated?  i.e. It would contain say, an email with a token that could have only been created by service X; and providing the JWT is legit, the system would know it contains true info?  Then there would be no need for my system to independently call Google/FB/etc?  (reading the blog post now)

Comment: yes. The JWT is a self contained entity with information about the user: (e.g. name, email) or the user in relation with your API (e.g. user is an "admin"). It is digitally signed, so you can check integrity. You can check the signature in your backend without an additional request to the server, it would just be a crypto function.

Comment: I still don't understand how this could be absolutely secure.  I followed the advice in your blog post (really helpful!)  I think the only way to make this secure is to have the server use the access_token it receives and query it against the service (google/fb/...)  Most secure way I can think of is forming a JWT (like you suggest) using one key (e.g. email) as the 'sub' in the claims, and the user id as the secret.  But even that could be faked.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post @eugenio-pace mentioned was really helpful for setting up the client side.

For the server side though, the `access_token` should be validated.

The SDK's are (in composer) (code below):

- Facebook: `"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"`
- Google: `cURL` request (didn't care for `"google/apiclient"`)
- SoundCloud: `"ise/php-soundcloud": "3.*"`

(There are others of course, just these three were the ones I chose, and seem decent.)

Last time I did something like this I made the mistake of validating the `access_token` on every request, which had a huge (obviously negative) impact on performance.  Now I just validate it on login and use it to retrieve the user's ID from that service.  So, the browser sends me access_token `A` and says it's from Facebook, I use the sdk above the the `access_token` with Facebook, and I get back their ID so I know they are who they say they are.

I'd suggest storing the `access_token` on the server with the `expires_in`.

(*I haven't dealt with refresh token's yet*)

Code to validate tokens using the above libraries:

```
function validateTokenFacebook($token, $id=null) {
    // Performed above
    // FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($config->fb->app_id, $config->fb->secret);

    $session = new FacebookSession($token);

    // Fetch user info
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    try {
        $response = $request->execute();
    } catch (\Facebook\FacebookServerException $e) {
        $this->mlog->err($e . "\n" . $e->getTraceAsString());
        throw new AuthTokenInvalidException();
    }

    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    $user_id = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
    return array(access_token, $user_id);
}
function validateTokenGoogle($token, $id=null) {
    $resp=array();

    // This key isn't included in the token from hello.js, but
    // google needs it
    if (!array_key_exists('created', $token)) $token['created'] = $token['expires'] - $token['expires_in'];

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($this->systemConfig->google->app_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($this->systemConfig->google->secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($this->systemConfig->google->redirectUri);
    $client->setScopes('email');
    $client->setAccessToken(json_encode($token));

    try {
        // Send Client Request
        $objOAuthService = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $userData = $objOAuthService->userinfo->get();
        return array($token['access_token'], $userData['id']);
    } catch (\Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
        throw new AuthException('Google returned ' . get_class($e));
    }
}
function validateTokenSoundcloud($token, $id=null) {
    $soundcloud = new \Soundcloud\Service(
        $this->systemConfig->soundcloud->app_id,
        $this->systemConfig->soundcloud->secret,
        $this->systemConfig->soundcloud->redirect);
    $soundcloud->setAccessToken($access_token);
    try {
        $response = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'), true);
        if (array_key_exists('id', $response))
            return array($access_token, $response['id']);
    } catch (Soundcloud\Exception\InvalidHttpResponseCodeException $e) {
        $this->mlog->err($e->getMessage());
    }
    throw new AuthTokenInvalidException();
}
```

I have a few custom classes above, such as the Exceptions and the systemConfig, but I think it's verbose enough to communicate what they do.